# A puzzle question asked in mathematics exam

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I am self studying for an exam and I am unable to solve this quiz question.

[image: puzzle]

I tried to find the numbers in the sentences but I couldn't find them and I think that's a wrong approach.

Can anyone please tell how to solve this question?

The correct answer is

> B.

Comment: I am curious what sort of exam this would be useful self-study for

Comment: @Kate aptitude exam( reasoning) for evaluation of scientific temperament.

Comment: Honestly, not understanding this question shows more aptitude for reasoning then solving this question.An important step is to go from a representation (letters) to the abstract entity (meaning). So this question is much easier for people who do not automatically do that. (and for other people who know this types of question beforehand)

Comment: @lalala I don't follow. An inability (or difficulty) to apply reason to answer the question shows an aptitude for reasoning?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Numbers in bold:

> Tins**el even**t (eleven)
>  Ma**n in E**nglang (nine)
>  Good h**eight** (eight)
>  Las**t en**counter (ten)

Giving the order:

> Ascending 8, 9, 10, 11 which corresponds to answer B.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, I completely mis-understood the question but got the same answer. I'm just posting this here for mild amusement.

> Tinsel event - can only mean Christmas, which is the 25th of December
>  Man in England - if we're looking for a specific man, then the most notable is the Prime Minister, who lives at 10 Downing Street
>  Good height - completely stumped me (for good reason)
>  Last encounter - maybe related to the 11th hour, again slightly stumped here

> At this point, I looked at the possible answers and saw that A and C started with 25, which would be impossible given that I "know" there's a 10 in there. As such, B and D are the only remaining options. If it's D, then Last Encounter would need to be less than 10, but I thought it may be 11. As such, I'd guess at B.

Like I said, it's completely off base and misses the actual pattern, it just made me smile.

Comment: your answer is very nice reasoning !!

Comment: I like it! Much more lateral-thinking than mine. Good height could be 6. In the US it's a stereotype that a man at least 6 feet tall will set the ladies' hearts aflutter. And this would give the same answer in the multiple choice! (No spoiler tag or encoding in this comment since at this point we are just finding funny things that fit the clues. )